# GridView Templatefield date formatting not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, gridview

Code on aspx:

```
<EditItemTemplate>  
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Release_Dt", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
        <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="Release_Dt_vdt1"  
        ControlToValidate="TextBox12" onservervalidate="validate_dt"   
        ErrorMessage="enter valid date" ValidationGroup="UpdateVdtGrp" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true">  
    </asp:CustomValidator>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Validation code (in code behind):

```
    protected void validate_dt(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)  
    {  
        DateTime minDate = DateTime.Parse("1000/12/28");
        DateTime maxDate = DateTime.Parse("9999/12/28");
        DateTime dt;

        args.IsValid = (DateTime.TryParse(args.Value, out dt)
                        && dt <= maxDate
                        && dt >= minDate);
    }
```

Question:  The date format keeps changing from "yyyy-MM-dd" to short / long date format as shown below every time the row is updated (even just clicking "edit" and "update" on the default gridview buttons without changing any content / dedicated editing 'textbox12').  **What is the cause, and how could we fix it?**

I have clarify that the SQL database connected to, which this data is stored as string, does not auto-format the data when updated.

If I am missing some piece of important info for the question please advise, thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: are you not using `Dataformatstring` property anywhere else? make sure that.

Comment: check to see if there are any other templates associated with the textbox in the gridview... also put break points on the server side and see how to the code is traversed... maybe that will give you a clue as to where the format is changed..

Comment: @Rahul thanks I did use find function to make sure no 'Dataformatstring' is use anywhere in the code

Comment: @Philo to make sure on that, I make sure 'textbox12' does not exist anywhere in my code, this should give enough to tell that no other templates assocated with this textbox?

Comment: Nevermind guys i found where the problem is:  a set of asp:parameter for <updateParameters> are set to type: Datetime, causing this.  I am now storing the data as string to avoid this problem.